# Как удалить строку из таблицы?

Tags: javascript, ajax

есть код который ajax-ом удаляет запись из БД, он работает, но как сделать чтобы при успешном удалении строка таблицы исчезала без перезагрузки страницы ?

Код html:

```
<table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px;">
            <thead class="table-secondary">
                <tr>
                    <th>№</th>
                    <th>ОВД</th>
                    <th>ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ</th>
                    <th>ТИП ТЕХНИКИ</th>
                    <th>ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ</th>
                    <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
                    <th>СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
                    <th>ИНВЕНТАРНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
                    <th>ВВОД В ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЮ</th>
                    <th>ДЕЙСТВИЯ</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-light">
                <?php if (!empty($restechinfo)) {
                    foreach ($restechinfo as $resinfo) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><?php echo  $resinfo->name_ovdrb; ?></a></td>
                            <td style="max-width: 150px;"><?php echo  $resinfo->name_subdivision; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->type; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->manufacture; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->model; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->serial_number; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->inventary_number; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $resinfo->date; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="bttnaction">
                                    <div class="bttnactiongroup">
                                        <button data-id="<?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?>" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=10 class="text-center table-danger">НЕТ ДАННЫХ</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

js код:

```
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.delete', function(e) { // ловим клик по классу удалить
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id'); // получаем значение атрибута data именно класса этого по которому кликнули и дальше это все дело отправляем
        if (confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись ?")) {

            if (!!id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/func_admin.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        "id": id
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.result == "good") {
                            alert(data.html);
                          
                        } else if (data.result == 'error') {
                            alert(data.html);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Код не мой, нашел его на форуме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатие на кнопку `.delete` ищем родителя который отвечает за строку таблицы (`tr`) при помощи метода [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), далее удаляем при помощи [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.table').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('delete') && confirm('Удалить эту строку?')) {
      let target = e.target,
          id = target.getAttribute('data-id');
      console.log('data-id='+id+' - deleted');
      target.closest('tr').remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px;">
  <thead class="table-secondary">
    <tr>
      <th>№</th>
      <th>ОВД</th>
      <th>ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ</th>
      <th>ТИП ТЕХНИКИ</th>
      <th>ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ</th>
      <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
      <th>СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
      <th>ИНВЕНТАРНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
      <th>ВВОД В ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЮ</th>
      <th>ДЕЙСТВИЯ</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-light">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="#">name_ovdrb;</a></td>
      <td style="max-width: 150px;">name_subdivision;</td>
      <td>type;</td>
      <td>manufacture;</td>
      <td>model;</td>
      <td>serial_number;</td>
      <td>inventary_number;</td>
      <td>date;</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bttnaction">
          <div class="bttnactiongroup">
            <button data-id="1" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="#">name_ovdrb;</a></td>
      <td style="max-width: 150px;">name_subdivision;</td>
      <td>type;</td>
      <td>manufacture;</td>
      <td>model;</td>
      <td>serial_number;</td>
      <td>inventary_number;</td>
      <td>date;</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bttnaction">
          <div class="bttnactiongroup">
            <button data-id="2" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><a href="#">name_ovdrb;</a></td>
      <td style="max-width: 150px;">name_subdivision;</td>
      <td>type;</td>
      <td>manufacture;</td>
      <td>model;</td>
      <td>serial_number;</td>
      <td>inventary_number;</td>
      <td>date;</td>
      <td>
        <div class="bttnaction">
          <div class="bttnactiongroup">
            <button data-id="3" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ещё я сохраняю в переменную `id` значение атрибута `data-id`, т.к. думаю удалить ещё нужна на сервере, а т.к. она задаётся переменной из **PHP** (`$resinfo->id_spravtech;`), думаю её надо передавать через **AJAX**, но это уже ~~другая история~~ вопрос.

Comment: а как это вставить в мой код? Чтобы после Alert подтверждения строка удалилась?

Comment: if (data.result == "good") {
                            alert(data.html);
                          
                        }  вот сюда его запихнуть надо ?

Comment: [`alert()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm#alert) выводит только сообщение, для окна по типу "да\нет" используется [`confirm()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm#confirm). Обновил ответ.